# Accessing light sensor raw data

Tags: sensors

Is it possible to access light sensor raw data logs from an Android device (in my case, an LG Optimus)? If so, how is this possible and what format would the log be in?

Comment: What makes you sure that the data is logged and not just available as a service for subscription?

Answer (score 1):

The Android system monitors the light sensor (for things like auto-adjusting the backlight), but to my knowledge doesn't specifically log that data by default.

You can get an app like [AndroSensor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fivasim.androsensor) which allows access to all your phone sensors and can monitor and log the data for you.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, although Android does have light sensor data, it does not store it anywhere (as far as I'm aware anyway). Luckily, there is a *very* simple way of accessing and storing the data yourself!

Just follow the steps below, and you should be up and running with light sensor data in no time!

---

1. Download **[Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)** from the **Play Store**
2. Make a new **.txt** file in your documents folder and name it to `Light_sensor_data.txt` (You may need a file viewer/editor such as **[File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.fx)**).
3. Open **Tasker** and click `+` → **Event** → **System** → **Device Boot.**
4. Click on the gear (back) in the top left corner.
5. A pop-up menu will appear. Tap on **New Task** and name it `Light Sensor Data` (Or whatever you want).
6. Within the task, click on `+` → **File** → **Write File**.
7. To the right of where it says **File**, there is a magnifying glass; Click on it.
8. Now tap **Documents** → **Light_sensor_data.txt**
9. Click the "pencil" to the right of **Text.** Now scroll down the list that says **Variable Select** and find **Light Level**. It is close to the middle.
10. Now click the **Gear** or <kbd>Back</kbd> button.
11. Tap `+` → **Task** → **Wait**. If you need your results to update quickly, I would suggest setting **MS** to anywhere between `10` and `100`, however this will use a lot of CPU so if you're ok with slower updating results, I would set **Seconds** to between `1` and `5`.
12. Once again, click on the **Gear** (back). Now select `+` → **Task** → **Goto** and set **Type** to `Action Number` and **Number** to `1`.
13. Tap the **Gear** (back) twice to get to the **Tasks** screen. Now click **Profiles** at the top of the screen.
14. Tap on `+` → **Event** → **System** → **Device Boot** and click the **Gear** (back). A menu should pop-up; select **Light Sensor Data.**
15. On the **Profiles** tab there should be a **On/ Off** switch to the right of your **Task.** Turn it to <kbd>Off</kbd> and then back to <kbd>On</kbd>.
16. Restart your device.

**Important note**: not only you must have a light sensor on your device, but it must also be enabled. You can check if it is enabled or not by hitting the three dots in the upper right corner of tasker → Preferences and selecting the *monitor* tab.  Now scroll down to *Light Sensor* and ensure that *Yes* is selected.

---

Given that everything was setup properly, you should now be able to access light levels by reading **Light_sensor_data.txt**   You can also *read* the light level data using **Tasker** and even create a pop-up displaying the current information.

Good luck, and I hope this helps you.

Comment: Are you somehow affiliated with Tasker? I ask this because all your answers involve the app and as the [Help Center](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) states: "The community here tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you **must** disclose your affiliation in your answers."

Comment: @onik    No I am not in any way affiliated with tasker, it's just really the only part of android that I feel I know a lot about. Therefore, I mostly just answer questions that can be solved using it. As far as android goes, I sort of "specialize" in developing apps using tasker and plugins for it. But no, although I would like to work for them, I don't:) Nor do I have any affliations to anything related to tasker.   If you look closely at my user icon, it says "IdeasEtc" thats my business.

Answer (score 1):

I have a rooted Samsun 7 device (sm-g935v) and I can read the raw data from:
`/sys/class/sensors/light_sensor/lux`

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to access it is to install [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux), a Linux terminal emulator that gives you access to the Linux commands on Android. On Samsung A3, you can access the data with

```
cat /sys/class/sensors/light_sensor/lux 
cat /sys/class/sensors/light_sensor/raw_data  #alternative
```

You can install Python with Termux and write a Python script that will read the content of these files, and publish it on any Pub/sub system with MQTT. I've tried Mosquitto, and it works perfectly with Termux. You can even publish to cloud IOT of either AWS or Microsoft or Google. Any IoT broker will do.